# Custom OnPreferenceChangeListener never invoked

Tags: android, listener, android-preferences

I have written a class which implements Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener and whose OnPreferenceChange method should be invoked when the Preference is changed. Although I set these listener, the method never is invoked.

```
public abstract class Program
    implements Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener,
                Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener {

/// reference to main activity
public static MainActivity mainActivity;
/// stores the keys to all preferences
protected final HashMap<String, String> PreferenceCodes = new HashMap<>();

public void setPreferenceListeners (PreferenceFragment Host) {
    // iterate over all Preferences
    for(HashMap.Entry<String, String> entry : PreferenceCodes.entrySet()) {
        Preference tmp = Host.findPreference(entry.getKey());
        tmp.setOnPreferenceClickListener(this);
        tmp.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(this);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
    // TODO Here is the problem: This method never is invoked

    Toast.makeText(mainActivity, "Changed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    return true;/        
}

@Override
public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
    Toast.makeText(mainActivity, "Click", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    return true;
}
```

The OnPreferenceClick method is correctly called, just the Change method troubles.
When I replace setPreferenceListeners with this code, everything works:

```
public void setPreferenceListeners (PreferenceFragment Host) {
    for(HashMap.Entry<String, String> entry : PreferenceCodes.entrySet()) {
        Preference tmp = Host.findPreference(entry.getKey());
        tmp.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
                Toast.makeText(mainActivity, "Change", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.i("TEST", "Change");
                return true;
            }
        });

        tmp.setOnPreferenceClickListener(this);
    }
```

I can't find my mistake. Where is the difference between OnPreferenceChange and OnPreferenceClick. It would be really nice to be able to implement both methods as a part of the Program class.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You many be required an **onSharedPreferenceListener**

Code Sample:

```
OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener listener;

listener = new SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() {
    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences prefs, String key) {

        //preference has been changed now, but Do your work.
    }
};

SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(getPackageName() + "_preferences", MODE_PRIVATE);
prefs.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(listener);
```

Comment: So what's the purpose of the OnPreferenceChangeListener class? If I want to prevent preferences from getting persistent I cannot use OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener, can I?